# Oracle nested table constraints

Tags: sql, oracle

how to add CHECK constraints into a nested table in oracle?

Object types:

```
Depend_t (depname: varchar2(12), gender: char(1), bdate: date, relationship:varchar2(10))
```

*Dependtb_t table of Depend_t*

```
Emp_t (eno: number(4), ename: varchar2(15), edept: ref dept_t, salary: number(8,2),
```

*dependents: dependtb_t)*

```
Dept_t (dno: number(2), dname: varchar2(12), mgr ref emp_t)
Proj_t (pno: number(4), pname: varchar2(15), pdept ref dept_t, budget: number(10,2))
Work_t (wemp: ref emp_t, wproj: ref proj_t, since: date, hours: number(4,2))
```

**Tables:**

```
Emp of Emp_t (eno primary key, edept references dept, nested table dependents store as dependent_tb)

Dept of Dept_t (dno primary key, mgr references emp)
Proj of Proj_t (pno primary key, pdept references dept)
Works of Works_t (wemp references emp, wproj references proj)
```

The `Emp, Dept,` and `Proj` tables contain tuples for all employees, departments and projects respectively. The attributes of `Emp` are `employee number (eno), name (ename), employee’s department (edept), salary` and the set of dependents stored as a nested table. The relationship attribute may have only `‘SPOUSE’` or `‘CHILD’` as values, gender may be `‘M’` or `‘F’`, and `bdate` records the birth date of the dependant.

here how could add the `'M'` or `'F'` constraint in nested table?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using a nested table and not a heap table that's got a foreign key back to the parent table? You could then quite cheerfully add the desired constraints to the child table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Oracle 12C SQL Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/constraint.html#GUID-1055EA97-BA6F-4764-A15F-1024FD5B6DFE):

> **Restrictions on Check Constraints**
>
> Check constraints are subject to the following restrictions:
>
> ...
>
> - Conditions of check constraints cannot contain the following
>     constructs:
>
>   ...
>
>   - Nested table columns or attributes
>       ...

This is one of many reasons why nested tables are almost **never** used in real databases, only in courses that explore all the features of Oracle!